# how do i output a checkbox details when a value is in use

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on what to do, to display a value like "large pizza £5.50" in my basket div. the problem is i already have two java codes, one for at least 1 must be ticked and another display order total in the basket.  How can i display the order total and also the description for each box ticked in the basket too. i already have a value assigned to each for the price so I don't know where to go next. I am fairly new to JavaScript so if anyone make a working version "the JavaScript code" I would be so grateful.

Below is the code that is relevant but not the complete page. There is 14 checkboxes in total as shown in the JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateFunction() {
        var fo = document.formname;
        if (!fo.field1.checked && !fo.field2.checked && !fo.field3.checked &&
            !fo.field4.checked && !fo.field5.checked && !fo.field6.checked && !fo.field7.checked && !fo.field8.checked && !fo.field9.checked && !fo.field10.checked && !fo.field11.checked && !fo.field12.checked && !fo.field13.checked && !fo.field14.checked) {
            alert("You must select at least one option.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    function totalIt() {
        var input = document.getElementsByClassName("product");
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i].checked) {
                total += parseFloat(input[i].value);

            }
        }
        document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>

<form name="formname" id="payment" onsubmit="return validateFunction();">

    <!-- select pizza section  -->
    <fieldset>
        <legend> select your pizza </legend>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field1" class="product" value="5.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> small £5.50</p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field2" class="product" value="8.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> medium £8.50</p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field3" class="product" value="11.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> large £11.50</p>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="basket">
        <h3> Basket </h3>
        <p>Order Total
            <input value="£0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total" /> </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using newer browsers you can use datasets:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVQJMr)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateFunction() {
  var fo = document.formname;
  if (!fo.field1.checked && !fo.field2.checked && !fo.field3.checked &&
    !fo.field4.checked && !fo.field5.checked && !fo.field6.checked && !fo.field7.checked && !fo.field8.checked && !fo.field9.checked && !fo.field10.checked && !fo.field11.checked && !fo.field12.checked && !fo.field13.checked && !fo.field14.checked) {
    alert("You must select at least one option.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName("product");
  var total = 0;
  var contents = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      var article = input[i];
      total += parseFloat(article.value);
      contents += article.dataset.desc + '<br/>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = contents;
  document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
<form name="formname" id="payment" onsubmit="return validateFunction();">
<!-- select pizza section  -->
<fieldset>
    <legend> select your pizza </legend>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" data-desc="foo" name="field1" class="product" value="5.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> small £5.50</p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" data-desc="bar" name="field2" class="product" value="8.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> medium £8.50</p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" data-desc="bam" name="field3" class="product" value="11.50" onclick="totalIt()" /> large £11.50</p>
</fieldset>

<div id="basket">
    <h3> Basket </h3>
  <div id="contents">
  </div>
    <p>Order Total
        <input value="£0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total" /> </p>
</div>
```

[data- reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)